Unable to register sip in Twilio sip domain from my flutter mobile application using the sip_us package
I am using the sip_ua package in my flutter application to make a sip connection with twilio sip domain. I have used Zoiper to test my sip domain and it works fine, and I can see the registered sip data on my Twilio SIP domain. But when I try to use the same credentials in my flutter application with sip_ua package, it does not work and gives me an error. Am I missing something? Stuck here for 3 weeks. Any help will be really appreciated.
Below is my SIP data I am using to register with Twilio.
These are my credentials I am using to make a SIP connection with Twilio, using the sip_ua^1.0.0 package:
final SIPUAHelper helper = SIPUAHelper();
final UaSettings settings = UaSettings();
helper.addSipUaHelperListener(this);
settings.webSocketUrl = "wss://flu.sip.us1.twilio.com:443"; // Twilio WSS URL
settings.uri = "sip:101@flu.sip.us1.twilio.com"; // SIP URI
settings.authorizationUser = '101'; // Authorization user (username)
settings.password = '*******'; // Password for SIP user
settings.displayName = 'Display name';

settings.register_expires = 3600;
await helper.start(settings);
helper.register();

***below is the error log i am getting in response.
`I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:56:32.925] Level.debug websocket_interface.dart:87 ::: connecting to WebSocket wss://flu.sip.us1.twilio.com:443
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:56:32.951] Level.info websocket_dart_impl.dart:26 ::: connect wss://flu.sip.us1.twilio.com:443, {}, [sip]
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:56:33.7] Level.debug ua.dart:183 ::: register()
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:56:33.11] Level.warning registrator.dart:135 ::: <sip:lciozuob@6fm513517h47.invalid;transport=wss>;+sip.ice;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:43dc2fcf-d8e8-4904-9b6d-54effaf231a7>"
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:56:33.33] Level.debug transport.dart:145 ::: send()
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:56:33.35] Level.error transport.dart:148 ::: unable to send message, transport is not connected. Current state is 1
I/flutter (25365): transport.dart:151
I/flutter (25365): non_invite_client.dart:46
I/flutter (25365): request_sender.dart:74
I/flutter (25365): registrator.dart:274
I/flutter (25365): ua.dart:185
I/flutter (25365): sip_ua_helper.dart:73
I/flutter (25365): webrtc_service.dart:92
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:56:33.39] Level.debug non_invite_client.dart:53 ::: transport error occurred, deleting transaction z9hG4bK3870384
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:56:33.46] Level.debug sip_ua_helper.dart:179 ::: registrationFailed => Code: [500], Cause: SIP Failure Code, Reason: Connection Error
I/flutter (25365): Registration state changed-------------------------RegistrationStateEnum.REGISTRATION_FAILED
...
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:58:46.721] Level.debug websocket_interface.dart:167 ::: WebSocket wss://flu.sip.us1.twilio.com:443 closed
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:58:46.724] Level.debug sip_ua_helper.dart:158 ::: disconnected => Code: [0], Cause: error, Reason: Client send disconnect
I/flutter (25365): Transport state changed-------------------------TransportStateEnum.DISCONNECTED
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:58:46.727] Level.debug transport.dart:183 ::: reconnection attempt: 2. next connection attempt in 4 seconds
I/flutter (25365): [2024-09-06 21:58:46.731] Level.error websocket_interface.dart:131 ::: close() | error closing the WebSocket: Null check operator used on a null value`


Zoiper works fine as it uses TCP/TLS/UDP transport.
Sip_ua uses websocket ws/wss transport, which is not supported by Twilio:
Twilio sip call is not working from tryit.jssip.net.
As alternative solution check Siprix flutter plugin https://github.com/siprix/FlutterPlugin,
which can make SIP connections over TCP/TLS/UDP and uses webrtc for media.
